# What would the time complexity be of running DFS on each node in a graph?

Tags: graph, time-complexity, big-o, depth-first-search

I have to write a function that performs DFS on each node in a directed graph. I believe the run time would be `O(n^2+mn)` but I am not positive about this. Would this be considered polynomial time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be considered polynomial:

Everything thing that has a time complexity of O( n^k ), n \in \N is polynomial.

You have O( n^2 + mn ), m can be written as m = n*u, u \in \R; Now you can insert if:
n^2 + u*n*n = n^2 + u*n^2 = ( 1 + u ) * n^2. ( 1 + u ) is a constant value, so it is negligible.

Therefore, you have the form of a polynomial time: O( n^2 ) (k=2).